# Sharing Front-End Access Database

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access back-end database with tables, queries, reports...and I have an Access front-end database with a data-entry form that will be used by 3 users. Both back- and front-ends are in same folder on a file server accessible to all 3 users.

What is the proper method of sharing my Access front-end database? Is it simply to have each user make a copy of it and put it on their local drive? This is my first time sharing a database, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is the front-end locked down (for design) and properly linked to the back-end?  If they are, you will need to go back to your development copy, save it on the end-users' machines individually, and re-link to the databases on the file server.  i have a VBA script that runs when the front-end starts up that checks for the existence of the backend.  if the backend is missing or has been moved, it prompts the user (or dba) for the new location.  I will provide you some more information later this evening if you are interested.  My front-end is packaged as a standalone application that resides on the end-users' computers. The backend resides on their server.  This is much safer and faster than having your users run the front-end from a networked location.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that, after linking, you should "lock-down" the front-end on the users' computers. You don't want them fiddling around with your form design.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, after linking, you should "lock-down" the front-end on the users' computers.  You don't want them fiddling around with your form design.